# Return the Branch in a Data Tree Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to return the branches in a Data Tree. Currently my code only returns the first branch.

```
data DTree a = Leaf a | Branch a (DTree a) (DTree a) deriving (Show)
get_b :: DTree Int -> [Int]
get_branches (Branch x _ _) = [x]
get_branches (Branch _ l r)  = get_branches r ++ get_branches l
```

Example output

```
ghci > get_branches (Branch 2 (Leaf 3) (Branch 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 5)))
[2]
```

Comment: Remember to pattern match the right constructor. Together with a slight tweak in the recursive case (the second case) and you're good to go!

Comment: Always keep warnings enabled: doing so would spot two issues in your code. 1) the patterns are not exhaustive, and 2) the patterns are overlapping (the second equiation will never be taken). Fixing these issues will make you closer to a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Comment: This data structure is too restriced. Try to construct one with 2 elements. Actually, can only contain an odd number of `a`s.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is something youre looking for?

```
get_branches :: DTree Int -> [Int]
get_branches (Branch x l r)  = [x] ++ get_branches r ++ get_branches l
get_branches (Leaf x) = [x]
```

There is no base case for your function. So use the pattern 'Leaf'.

Additionally, the patterns (Branch x _ _) (Branch _ l r) are the same pattern, except with (Branch _ l r) you get the left and right branch.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell will perform pattern matching from top to bottom. Since a `Branch &hellip … …` is matched by the first clause it will *never* trigger the second clause. Furthermore your program does not cover the `Leaf` case.

If you want to construct a list of values in the inodes (the `Branch`es), then we can work with:

```
get_branches :: DTree a -> [a]
get_branches (Leaf _) = []
get_branches (Branch x l r)  = x : get_branches r ++ get_branches l
```

here we first return the value of the branch, and then the values of the branches of the subtrees (first the left subtree and then the right subtree). For example with:

```
get_branches :: DTree a -> [a]
get_branches (Leaf _) = []
get_branches (Branch x l r)  = get_branches r ++ x : get_branches l
```

this will result in a lot of appending, which is linear in the size of the first list. We can prevent this by making calls where we pass a recursive call as tail, so:

```
get_branches :: DTree a -> [a]
get_branches = go []
  where go tl (Leaf _) = tl
        go tl (Branch x l r) = go (x : go tl r) l
```

Comment: Really in depth answer, learned a lot. Thank you!